# LL(1) grammar. How to calculate follow set if one has self-recursion rules?

Tags: parsing, grammar, context-free-grammar, compiler-construction

According to the rules from this [paper](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~cs415/reading/FirstFollowLL.pdf) :

> 1. If A is the start nonterminal, put EOF in FOLLOW(A)
>      Find the productions with A on the right-hand-side:
> 2. For each production X → αAβ, put FIRST(β) − {EPSILON } in FOLLOW(A)
> 3. If EPSILON is in FIRST(β) then put FOLLOW(X) into FOLLOW(A)
> 4. For each production X → αA, put FOLLOW(X) into FOLLOW(A)

I have next piece in my grammar:

```
 ...
    A -> C B
    B -> , A
    C -> EPSILON
    C -> =
    B -> ;
 ...
```

When I try to calculate FOLLOW(B) according to the rule 4 I have to calculate FOLLOW(A) and vice versa. So I have StackOverflowException because of self-recursion.

What should I do?

Comment: Maybe better ask on [cs.se]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use recursion. You iterate, calculating the `FOLLOW` set based on what was calculated on the previous iteration:

1. If A is the start nonterminal, put *EOF* (a new terminal indicating the end of input) in F[0](A).
2. For each production X → αAβ, put FIRST(β) − {EPSILON} in F[n](A),
3. and if EPSILON is in FIRST(β) then put F[n-1](X) into F[n](A)
4. For each production X → αA, put F[n-1](X) into F[n](A).
5. Stop when F[n](*) == F[n-1](*)

FOLLOW(*) == F[n](*)